# Physical meaning of fixed point of a function?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

A fixed point of a function $f(x)$ is $x$ where $f(x) = x$.

And if we consider a function as an operator, then the fixed point is the invariant point of that operator.

Generally the invariant points of an operator would have some interesting physical meanings, like the eigenvectors of a matrix($Av = \lambda v$), eigenfunction of differentiation ($e^x = \frac{de^x}{dx}$).

So I am wondering if there are any cool explanation for the physical meaning of the fixed point of any random function?

Say if $f(x) = x^2$, then $x = 1$ is the fixed point, as $f(1) = 1^2 = 1$. Anything make the point $x = 1$ special for $f(x) = x^2$?

Comment: There is no physical meaning in a function. It is a mathematical object. What makes $1$ special in the square function is that it equals itself when multiplied by itself.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, suppose you want to compute $\sqrt{x}$ an old-fashioned way. You start with a guess $y$, and then obtain a new, hopefully better guess,
$$
           y_1 = \frac{1}{2}(x/y+y).
$$
If $y > \sqrt{x}$, then $x/\sqrt{y} < \sqrt{x}$. So, an average of the two is a good guess for a closer approximation. If you continue this game, you end up with a fixed point $y_{\infty}$ that is a fixed point of the algorithm:
$$
           2y_{\infty}=x/y_{\infty}+y_{\infty} \\
            y_{\infty}^2 = x.
$$
You get a lot of digits of precision fairly quickly with this algorithm. Try it for yourself. This is just one example of such a fixed point method.

Very often, Mathematical equations can be reduced to fixed point algorithms. Even generally classes of solutions of ODEs and even PDEs can be solved with fixed point methods. Reformulating solutions of various kinds in terms of fixed points then allows you to invoke knowledge about fixed point analysis.